# Empty folder being created by Wordpress, breaks site

Tags: redirect, directory

I have a page on my site at mysite.com/publish. This page leads to a members area where they can add/edit posts from the front end. For some reason, randomly as far as I can tell, Wordpress keeps adding an empty folder to the same folder that Wordpress is in. For instance, my WP install is in a sub-directory called wordpress-2013 which is inside my main public directory. Inside that main directory an empty directory called "Publish" keeps being created so when someone tries to visit mysite.com/publish an error is given because of that folder.

I'm not sure where to even start figuring out what might be wrong. Anyone have any ideas? I found a couple threads on here from about 4 years ago that either didn't have answers or did not apply to the current WP version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are your access permissions to the main directory? wordpress should not  be able to write to it otherwise you have a big security problem.

Comment: Nothing seems off with the permissions and you're probably correct that it's not WP creating the folder, I just can't figure out what actually is. I figured out a workaround to point people to the page us `bloginfo('wpurl')` instead of `bloginfo(url)` as the base URL, which forces WP to look in the WP sub-directory instead of the main directory for the page. But, I'm still curious why that folder keeps appearing. Hopefully someone else has an idea or has experienced this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a sub-directory set up with my hosting cPanel that I had completely forgotten about from long ago. I got rid of that and this is now fixed.